# Pandas Groupby by condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Say I have a df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], data=[[2, 1,1, 3],
                                                 [4, 2,3, 7],
                                                 [2, 4,7, 9],
                                                 [3, 2,9, 11],
                                                 [4, 3,11,15],
                                                 [5, 5,15,20],
                                                 [10,3,20,30]])
```

and i have an array of values (consists of some values from 'c', but can be of arbitrary length)

```
cuts=[3,11]
```

Is there a way to groupby by 'c', in 3 groups, so that in

1st there were values 'c'<3,

2nd there were values 3<= 'c' <11,

3rd there were values 'c'>11 ?

and then .apply('a':'sum','b':'max', 'd':'max')

One way would be to make a dict, and then map df['c'] apply a map. But I wonder if one can do that with groupby (faster).